# get param function array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, function, parameters

I want to get the array that I send in my function but it seem's to be empty.
I call `send_file();` with an array in the param

```
send_file($addr, @curfile);
```

And this is the way I get back the param

```
sub send_file($$)
{
    my $addr = $_[0];
    my @elem = @_;
    ...
}
```

Why `my @elem` is empty ? How could I get back the array without losing everything ?

Comment: Try to use a referece to the array as paramter `send_file($addr,  \@curfile);` ---> `my @elem = @{$_[1]`};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass your array by reference instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $test_scalar = 10;
my @test_array  = qw(this is a test);

sub test($\@)
{
    my ($scalar, $array) = @_;

    print "SCALAR = $scalar\n";
    print "ARRAY  = @$array\n";
}

test($test_scalar, @test_array);

system 'pause';
```

Output:

```
SCALAR = 10
ARRAY  = this is a test
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

### EDIT:

If you would like to do the same thing without passing by reference change your $$ to $@ and use shift so the first argument doesn't end up included in your array.  Passing arrays by reference is better coding practice though . . . This is just to show you how it can be done without passing by reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $test_scalar = 10;
my @test_array  = qw(this is a test);

sub test($@)
{
    my ($scalar, @array) = @_;

    print "SCALAR = $scalar\n";
    print "ARRAY  = @array\n";
}

test($test_scalar, @test_array);

system 'pause';
```

This will get you the same output.

You can also get rid of the $@ altogether if you would like it really isn't necessary.

Comment: @mpapec: My example wasn't inaccurate.  Try it out, an array reference is just a scalar and will be processed correctly by the subroutine if the array reference is declared using "$" in the function prototype.  It doesn't matter whether you use "$" or "\@" in the prototype, both will act the same. If you use the `ref()` function on an array reference passed in using both methods it will return "ARRAY" in both cases.  It recognizes the input as an array reference either way.

Comment: @mpapec: If you don't believe me just run my code and see that it acts the same :)

Comment: I was referring to second example. First was correct in functionality.

Comment: Ohhhhhh I see, I meant to say `$scalar = shift` instead of `$scalar = $_[0]` that way the scalar would be taken out of "@_" before the array was populated.  Nice catch, I just saw all of the format changes to the first one and assumed that it was the one you were talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use prototypes. Their purpose is to change parsing of the source which you don't need.

```
sub send_file
{
    my $addr = shift;
    my @elem = @_;
    ...
}

send_file($addr, @curfile);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why my @elem is empty ?

Your `@elem` is not empty, it has exactly two elements. First is value of `$addr` and second is size/number of elements in `@curfile` array. This is due `$$` [`prototype`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) definition which requires two scalars, so `scalar @curfile` is passed as second parameter.

> How could I get back the array without loosing everything ?

Since you're not using prototype advantages, just omit prototype part,

```
sub send_file {
    my ($addr, @elem) = @_;
    ...
}
```